# Why can't you put quotes around options of the cmd.exe executable?

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, cmd

In some automated tests I put double-quotes around every command given to an executable, e.g.

```
notepad "hello.txt"
```

This works correctly.  Also if I try the same with other executables this always seem to work.  However, the following doesn't work on Windows 7:

```
cmd.exe "/c" "echo hello"
```

The problem isn't the quotes around "echo hello", but it doesn't seem to like the quotes around the /c option.  All I get is the following output:

```
'"echo hello' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Is cmd.exe handled differently by Windows?

Comment: This question is rather interesting. I've never tried this before. Perhaps it is pulling in the quotes as part of the argument, and it's not handled for switches like `/c`?

Comment: What are you going to do when you find out why this is so? You can't change it, so roll with it!

Comment: @David, this problem is not blocking my further tests, but I want to understand why this works that way.  Knowing why this doesn't work can help me making other useful tests and help me understanding other things.

Comment: @Patrick I've given up trying to understand why things are the way they are at the Windows console! Perhaps I'm just too battle fatigued!

Comment: Strange. Seems like it only complains when both `/c` and `echo hello` are quoted. When only one of them or none, works as expected. Except, of course, the fact, that I wouldn't actually expect `"echo hello"` to work at all. :\

Comment: `cmd "/c" "echo hello"` certainly says `'"echo hello' is not recognized...` on my XP machine too.

Comment: @David Heffernan: To understand, why things are as they are, try a look at [the secrets of the batch parser](http://www.lingubender.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=615&sid=4c2b41c06fe1b23cdfe0356fd27407b3#p3531)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"hello.txt" is a filename, and in general you only quote filenames/paths (and other parameters that might contain spaces)

And yes, cmd.exe probably has some special handling, you can use /S to change the quote handling.

IMHO "/c" is bad practice anyway, it looks like you want to execute c.exe at the root of the current drive

Comment: Not completely the answer I was hoping, but the sentence "cmd.exe probably has some special handling" seems to indicate that there is more than magic behind Windows, and we probably will never know why things work this way.

Comment: @Patrick: Windows programs get the command line as a single string. How they are going to parse this is up to them.